# How do I get a count of results for a specific time period?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a screen with our orders on it and I want to show some counts for quick and easy reporting.

I have worked out that I can get a count of all orders by doing

```
<%= Order.count(:all) %>
```

I would also like to show some counts from specific date ranges, for example 'today', 'yesterday', 'this week', 'this month', 'last month, 'this year' etc.

I'm very new to rails, having recently made the leap from PHP so I'm still getting used to the Rails way of doing things. We're using Rails 3 and ActiveRecord to query the DB. What would be the best way to go about achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not use finders(or any logic) inside your views. Instead, put count as a class method for your order model, or make it a scope. Moreover, on Rails 3, it's better to use the new syntax (same for your count) :

```
Order.find(...).all
```

Now, you can use the created_at attribute of Rails models to do what you want. Then, you would just need to do something like :

```
Order.where("created_at > ?", 2.days.ago.to_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this example. You can pass in conditions to the count method.

```
Person.count(:conditions => "age > 26")

Order.count(:conditions => "created_at BETWEEN '2010-09-29' AND '2010-11-30'")
```

More [examples from the API documentation](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M000292)